# Averaging Over Hamming Weights

Tags: probability, combinatorics, soft-question, binary

**Question**: Let $\Sigma:=\{0,1\}.$ A finite string $,s,$ over $\Sigma$ is any finite sequence composed of $0s$ and $1s.$  The length of $s$ denoted $|s|$ counts the number of symbols comprising $s.$ The [Hamming weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight#:%7E:text=The%20Hamming%20weight%20of%20a,string%20of%20the%20same%20length.) of $s;$ which I will denote by $\mathcal{H}(s),$ counts the number of symbols in $s$ that differ from $0.$ What are some mathematical and more importantly physical interpretations of
$$
\frac{1}{|s|}\mathcal{H}(s) \label{a}\tag{1}
$$
?
Note I am not asking for an account of histories or common usages of Hamming weights. I am asking what averaging over Hamming weights informs us.

Edit: See Phicar's answer. It would appear $\ref{a}$ gives a density, *not a probability*, of the number of $1s$ in $s.$

---

I would think $\ref{a}$ gives the probability of drawing a $1$ among the symbols ( -bits) of $s.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $\frac{\mathcal{H}(s)}{|s|}$ gives you a value in between $0$ and $1$ that defines the density of $1's$ in the string. This is not quite a probability(you are evaluating non random points), but lets you compare strings of different sizes. If you do not divide by the length, the word $00100$ would have the same value as $1$ but the later seems more populated of $1's$ than the former.

Comment: do we have any resources or works that deal with the density of Hamming weights as you have defined it.

Comment: @AntonioHernandezMaquivar I would say that it depends more in what are you interested. Why are you interested in the quantity?

Comment: It would appear this quantity is related to a formula by Brylawski that computes the maximum number of elements covered by any element of $(P_{n},\leq) $; which is the lattice on the set of all integer partitions ordered by dominance.

Comment: I have been thinking about it but I do not see how to connect them. In the meantime, people call fractial/relative hamming distance to the hamming distance over the length.